# "Post Question/Answer" button disabled after connection failure

Tags: bug, asking-questions

Just now I tried posting a question/answer pair, and it happened that my computer was offline at that time. Instead of trying to load the new question (which is the default behavior) and get a connection timed out message, the "Post question/answer" button was disabled, a webpage reload didn't enable it. I had to navigate back to the Ask Question page again, only to find out my question/answer pair had already been posted (the saved draft also being there too).

If the computer is offline when sending a post, the disabled Post Question/Answer button should probably be fixed to the default behavior explained above. I almost posted an exact dupe of my question because of this, fortunately I caught it in time.